# How to set background of a form to a hexidecimal color in MS-Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am looking to set the background of a form to a hex value given a condition.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If Not IsNull(Me.SeparationDate) Then Me.Detail.BackColor = Val("&H" & "ff1111")
End Sub
```

Problem is that with this condition my background is turning a dark blue color and not an off red.

Comment: FYI `&HFF1111` is a legit hex literal, no need to make it a string then convert it to a double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value needs to be GBR

```
&H1111ff
```

There is also a `RGB()` function

```
RGB(255,17,17) 'Same as &H1111ff
```

Say you have

```
s = "ff1111"
```

Then you can do

```
Me.Detail.BackColor = RGB("&H" & Left$(s, 2), _
                          "&H" & Mid$(s, 3, 2), _
                          "&H" & Right$(s, 2))
```

or simply

```
Me.Detail.BackColor = "&H" & Right$(s, 2) & Mid$(s, 3, 2) & Left$(s, 2)
```

According to @MathieuGuindon the `Val` function is not required as VBA understands hex strings and automatically converts them to `Long`.

Comment: `&H1111FF` as a hex literal works just as well for the first case; no need to stringify it and convert it to a `Double` with `Val`, VBA understands hex literals perfectly fine =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: Thanks for the hint. Removed all `Val` functions.

Comment: That's what was tripping me up. Dang! So if I were to expand the code to allow the a superuser to pick the color and save it to a database, I would have to convert it coming in. Anyways I like this answer because it accomplishes what I am looking to do.